# Python: Parse CSV Data Between 2 Dates and Print in Ascending Order:

Tags: python, csv, datetime, parsing

I'm fairly new to Python so please excuse me if this question may be a simple fix or mistake. If you look at the code below i'm trying to parse data from a CSV file. Specially, i'm trying to parse the users created between two dates in ascending order. Any users created in between those two dates, should get printed out in ascending order. My date column `row[1]` in unix time. There is a word column `row[8]` that should also be printed. The goal is when the dates are parsed in ascending order the printed word column `row[8]` forms a specific phrase. The problem is when I execute the code as it is currently in Pycharm I receive an `IndexError: list out of range` at line 15 `creation_date = date.fromtimestamp(int(row[1]))`. I'm aware that Panda handles CSV files better, but i'm trying to avoid learning Panda for this one task.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, date
import sys

start_date = date(2014, 6, 22)
end_date = date(2014, 7, 22)

# Read csv data into memory filtering rows by the date in column 2 (row[1]).
csv_data = []
with open('sample.csv', newline='') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
header = next(reader)
csv_data.append(header)
for row in reader:
    creation_date = date.fromtimestamp(int(row[1]))
    if start_date <= creation_date <= end_date:
        csv_data.append(row)

if csv_data:  # Anything found?
# Print the results in ascending date order.
print(" ".join(csv_data[0]))
# Converting the timestamp to int may not be necessary (but doesn't hurt)
for row in sorted(csv_data[1:], key=lambda r: int(r[1])): 
    print(" ".join(row))
```

Comment: Does all your rows in csv  have 2 columns?

Comment: Madhan I've attaced a link to the CSV file through Google Drive. [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FvY9cNdZpBW8eO90G6nUI3UNeQ7iXqy1/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data that you are trying to access a value in the row that is not there (because there is only one value for this line).
You can wrap the code that is crashing in a `try/except` and see the line that is failing:

```
for row in reader: 
    try:
        creation_date = date.fromtimestamp(int(row[1]))
    except IndexError:
        print("Cannot get value for row: {}".format(row))
        continue

    if start_date <= creation_date <= end_date:
        csv_data.append(row)
```

That should give you a first idea for why it is crashing here (maybe your data is not tab-delimited?)

Comment: Not really an answer, but a good way to know more of the problem, so +1. But IMHO, the `if... append` part should be in the try block (creation_date was not set if IndexError)

Comment: Thank you both, i've tried both suggestions and i can see that the problem is that Python is unable to get the value for row[1]. Even after moving the if.....append statement as stated bySerge. I've also tried using the ,  delimiter with no results. It is a standard delimited CSV file created in Excel. If I use the \t delimiter the code at lease tries to execute but I still receive Cannot Get Value for every line as Python tries to parse the Data.

Comment: I've actually figured this out. You all got me on the right path. I had to specify the encoding of the CSV file as utf8 and I changed the delimiter back to ','. Now i can execute the code and get the results I want.

Answer (score 0):

the [csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FvY9cNdZpBW8eO90G6nUI3UNeQ7iXqy1/view?usp=sharing) you shared is  delimited with `,` . So when you say

```
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t') // returns a single column
```

You should replace it with

```
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
```

Actual Code:

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime, date
import sys

start_date = date(2014, 6, 22)
end_date = date(2014, 7, 22)

# Read csv data into memory filtering rows by the date in column 2 (row[1]).
csv_data = []
with open('sample_data.csv','r') as f:
 reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
 header = next(reader)
 csv_data.append(header)
 for row in reader:
    creation_date = date.fromtimestamp(int(row[1]))
    if start_date <= creation_date <= end_date:
        csv_data.append(row)

 if csv_data:  # Anything found?
    # Print the results in ascending date order.
    print(" ".join(csv_data[0]))
    # Converting the timestamp to int may not be necessary (but doesn't hurt)
    for row in sorted(csv_data[1:], key=lambda r: int(r[1])): 
        print(" ".join(row))
```

Comment: Thank you Madhan, from the help of the other 2 individuals and yourself. I have this working now!